# Converting phenotypes and genotypes to contingency tables in R

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

I have data that looks like this:

```
SNP        aa_controls       aA_controls       AA_controls       aa_cases       aA_cases      AA_cases
rs2378938   3412              16822             21987             2635           13197         16573
rs6712069   87                3354              38780             58             2659          29688
rs62445806  2306              15116             24799             1781           11497         19127
```

This continues for ~14k SNPS

I want to test if one or both of the two alleles are associated with higher risk of a disease for each SNP. So logically, I thought to first create a contingency table for each SNP that would look like this:

```
          aa     Aa      AA
case      #      #       #
control   #      #       #
```

So i can perform a chi-squared test for each SNP. However, I am having trouble re-configuring the data so a contingency table can be made. and then, after that apply a chi-squared to each table and store each p-value in a string or vector